# dynamic cell height with webImages

Tags: ios, uitableview

My tableview has few cells with images (for example index 1,3,4,6,9), images r loaded from web and i dont know their height.
 When image is downloaded i save it in dictionary (image.height forKey: index) and reload tableview.

in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dic keyEnumerator];
   id key;

   for (key in enumerator) {
       if (indexPath.row == [key integerValue]) { calculate cell height with image.height
   }
```

after scroll up, cell recalculate, how to cache height? Did u know better way to reload cell height after download images?

Comment: please show us some relevant code from your tableView... this except doesn't tell me much. :(

Comment: I do the same thing and I wonder e.g. why do you think you have to recalculate the height AFTER scrolling again

Comment: Use constant size for image view frames,image loading process take more time to load images in dictionary